# SQL Updating rows with data from other rows in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large table of records where the primary key is an item code which is an int.

Lots of the records are out of date and I want to replace the information in those rows with information in other rows while keeping the old primary key.

So if I had two rows:

```
ITEM_CODE   LANGUAGE    LABEL
12345678    ENG         OLD LABEL
87654321    EN-GB       NEW LABEL
```

Im looking to write an SQL statement that will leave me with the following table

```
ITEM_CODE   LANGUAGE    LABEL
12345678    EN-GB       NEW LABEL
87654321    EN-GB       NEW LABEL
```

When I looked at the UPDATE statement I was looking for something like

```
UPDATE table
SET  language1 and label1 WITH language2 and label 2 
WHERE item code1 = item code 2
```

Im doing this all in SQL Server Management Studio

Hope you can help.
Thanks

Comment: _"WHERE item code1 = item code 2"_ But those are different `ITEM_CODE`. How are they related?

Comment: Ya sorry they would be different. I meant it more of a way of specific the two item codes. As in the old one and the new one. WHERE is the wrong choice of word.

Comment: You still haven't specified how these records are related. Which records do you want to update with which others? You need to join this table with itself, but you have to know how. Since `ITEM_CODE` is the primary key you cannot link on this (since it's unique). But all the other columns are also different.

Comment: In sql server management studio, right click the table script table as  Create to. And post more than just two lines so we can help out.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like below:

```
UPDATE table SET  LANGUAGE = (Select LANGUAGE from table where ITEM_CODE = 87654321) 
                  LABEL    = (Select LABEL from table where ITEM_CODE = 87654321)
WHERE ITEM_CODE = 12345678
```

it will work for your example, also you can rewrite it in other syntax and ways.....

if you are a different  goal, please explain it more.

good luck